# prove dot product in Rn equals lengths time cosine of angle

Tags: normed-spaces

Well, its known to everyone that $$x,y \in\Bbb{R}^n, <x, y>= \sum{x_iy_i}$$. It is how we define inner product in $\Bbb{R}^n$. But we also know that it has geometric interpretation like $$<x, y> = \Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert cos{\theta} $$. My question is how you prove this is true? This question seems quite simple but It's surprising I don't find an answer trying to fix this problem via google.

It really bothers me sometimes because I've already gotten bachelor degree and I can't fix a straight forward problem like this....although im not in math major.

Answer (score 3):

Use the cosine rule.

Consider the triangle with vertices $0$, $x$ and $y$. It has side-lengths
$a=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$, $b=\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle}$ and $c=\sqrt{\langle x-y,x-y\rangle}$. Then
$$\cos\theta=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}.$$
Now put in the above expressions for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Oh that's it! why I don't think of ways like this.....thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary $n$, this is in fact taken as *definition* for the angle between vectors.
Nevertheless, whatever we mean by angle between vectors, it should be invariant under isometries, which are by definition linear maps $A\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$ that leave all lengths invariant, i.e., $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$. Then from $\langle x,y\rangle=\frac12(\| x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2)$, we see that isometries also respect scalar products, i.e., $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$.

One readily shows that there exists an isometry that takes any given vector $x\ne 0$ to a positive multiple of the first standard base vector $e_1$ and additionally takes $y$ to the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$. 
Hence we can restrict our investigation of angles to the $\Bbb R^2$ spanned by the first two base vectors and need only ask: How can we find the angle between vectors $x=(u,0)$ with $u>0$ and $y=(v,w)\ne(0,0)$? The latter vector can be written as $(v,w)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$ with $r=\sqrt{v^2+w^2}$ and the desired $\phi$. Comparing with $\|x\|^2=u^2$, $\|y\|^2=v^2+w^2=r^2$, and $\langle x,y\rangle = uv$, we see that in this special case (and per isometries: always) $\langle x,y\rangle=\|x\|\|y\|\cos\phi$.

Note that the above gives us only $\phi\in[0,\pi]$, not in $[0,2\pi)$. Indeed, while we could distinguish angles in $(0,\pi)$ from those in $(\pi,2\pi)$ by the sign of $w$, and we could exploit this for the case $n=2$ by requiring orientation-preserving isometries. But this makes no sense as soon as we are in $n\ge 3$ dimensions: There, we will always have another orientation-reserving isometry that produces $(u,0)$ and $(v,-w)$.

Comment: Wow you are right, I just use my intuition for the angle and suddenly it hits me, what is angle in space n >=3. It’s really amazing this intuitive way to define angle can be proved by the geometric way lord mentions above.

Comment: It interests me that if you define angle like this, how can you make sure this angle is same as angle we use in geometric world? Is it fair question?